# Probability that n is a prime in arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I read that a result that followed the PNT is the probability n is prime is $\frac{1}{\log(n)}$. Does is follow from the PNT on arithmetic progressions that the probability n is prime and is q mod a ( like 1 mod 4 or something ) is $\frac{1}{\phi(a) * \log(n) }$? Thank you

Comment: It certainly does provided $q$ is co-prime with $a$, and with the understanding that we are actually speaking about a *heuristic*, not about some rigorously defined probability distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from the PNT that when using the uniform distribution on $1 \ldots n$ letting $p_n$ be the probability that $X$ is prime then $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n \log n = 1$.

The probability that *$X$ is prime and $\equiv a \bmod q$* is $p_{n,a,q}$ and (by the PNT in arthmetic progressions) $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_{n,a,q} \log n$ doesn't depend on $a,gcd(a,q)=1$ thus $  \lim_{n \to \infty} p_{n,a,q} \phi(q) \log n = 1$.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a formal proof if possible.

Comment: @RyanShesler $p_n = \frac{\pi(n)}{n}$

Comment: @reuns your reasoning is very weird. you're saying PNT in arithmetic progressions implies $\lim_n p_{n,a,q}\log n$ doesn't depend on $a$ and *thus* $\lim_n p_{n,a,q} \phi(q)\log(n) = 1$. But PNT in arithmetic progressions just directly says $\lim_n p_{n,a,q} \phi(q)\log n = 1$. I doubt any version of it directly says it doesn't depend on $a$....